# Disproportional horizontal mouse speed with two monitors

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, touchpad

I'm using a laptop touchpad. Moving my finger from top to bottom of the pad, I can move the mouse pointer across the complete height of the screen. Moving my finger from left to right of the pad, I can move the mouse pointer across the complete width of the screen.

When I plug in a second monitor, the horizontal mouse speed suddenly doubles. Now I can move the pointer all the way across two monitors in a single swipe, but the vertical speed of the pointer has not changed.

This feels weird. Is there a way to keep the mapping of the pointer on the screen proportional to the aspect ratio of the touchpad? Ideally, something I won't need to tweak every time I plug in or disconnect an external monitor?

Comment: This is a real problem...

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing this issue as well in Ubuntu 11.10.

Try installing gpointing-device-settings:

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

Maybe it'll work for you by changing the mouse speed for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: The question is not in relation to scroll speed.

Comment: Fixed the wrong wording.